# How to insert the last comment in mySQL from a second table?

Tags: mysql

I have table with comments for posts where for one post could be few comments.

I am forming second table with post data which has to include just one (last) comment. So I have to join first table and find last comment in it.

```
TABLE 1: --id (of comment)---id (of post) --- comment 
TABLE 2: --id (of post) ---- comment
```

I have  prepared such request:

```
UPDATE table1.posts t1
        INNER JOIN table2.posts_comments t2 
             ON t1.id = t2.post_id
SET t1.comment = (SELECT comment FROM t2  ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1)
```

However it tell me that  t2 doesn't exist. Something wrong in a query or a false approach?

Comment: Do you really want to update _all_ records in `posts` with the single latest comment from the `posts_comments` table?  Can you add some sample data?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, exact! I mean not a single last comment in a table but last comment for that post id.

Comment: It won't work because in your sub-query you're trying to call a table alias `t2` from the outer query. How do you know the last comment from the `posts_comment` table? Is there any timestamp?

Comment: @tcadidot0 I order it by id: ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to store derived data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an update join with a subquery which finds the latest comment for each post:

```
UPDATE table1.posts t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT post_id, MAX(ID) AS max_id
    FROM table2.posts_comments
    GROUP BY post_id
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.post_id
INNER JOIN table2.posts_comments t3
    ON t2.post_id = t3.post_id AND t2.max_id = t3.ID
SET t1.comment = t3.comment;
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. Let me to  try this request.

Comment: I have 134 unique comments when I make this  request, the same as I make DISTINCT (posts_comments):     SELECT order_id, MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM `2205`.orders_comment
    GROUP BY order_id

Comment: However in a result it writes in t1.comment table just 117 rows. :( And there are no null or empty ones.

Comment: Aha, I see. These missing posts in second table where deleted, that's why there are only 117 rows were updated. Thank you for excellent query, I will never learn something like this. :)